# Inequality cannot be solved using Reduce (no transcendental functions)

Tags: equation-solving, inequalities

I have these assumptions:

```
aF = vF0 > 0 && vR0 > 0 &&
       bFx > 0 && rho > 0 && aRx > 0 && bRx > 0 && 
         bFx > bRx && 0 < vF0/bFx && vF0/bFx < rho && 
            rho < (aRx*rho + bRx*rho + vR0)/bRx
```

I cannot solve the following inequality with `Reduce` (output form visible in the last line):

```
SetSystemOptions["SimplificationOptions" -> "AssumptionsMaxNonlinearVariables" -> 100];
Assuming[
  aF, 
  Reduce[$Assumptions && (aRx^2 bFx rho^2 + aRx bFx bRx rho^2 - bRx vF0^2 + 2 aRx bFx rho vR0 + 2 bFx bRx rho vR0 + bFx vR0^2)/(2 bFx bRx) <= (aRx vF0^2 - bFx vF0^2 + 2 bFx vF0 vR0)/(2 bFx^2)]
]
```

> Reduce::nsmet: This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Reduce.

Can inequalities like this be solved in another way?

Comment: Please go here to see how to copy readable code from Mathematica: [How to copy code from Mathematica so it looks good on this site](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1584/27951).

Comment: Thanks for the link, but I use the free Wolfram Engine in a text terminal. I updated the question to explain why only a text form.

Comment: MMA version 13.1  I get "False" as result from Reduce.

Comment: @scriptfoo Does the Wolfram Engine in text mode only return the unreadable FullForm you show? I find that hard to believe. Can't you get the InputForm? Anyway, I tried to convert your equations to InputForm to make them more readable, but I also get `False` as the output. Note that you did not show us the contents of your `$Assumptions`, so we may not be able to properly reproduce your behavior.

Comment: @Daniel Yes, the inequality should always be false. I use Wolfram Engine 13.0.1. I'll try to install the newest version in a moment.

Comment: @MarcoB If you ask it to show an image, it only shows something like `-- graphics contents --`. `$Assumptions` is a local variable of `Assuming` (I am sorry if I use a wrong terminology) so here it has the same contents as `aF`.

Comment: @MarcoB After your prettify edits, WE actually returns false. It turns out, the text terminal randomly inserts spaces and it was the culprit which you corrected, consciously or not. Thanks!

Comment: @scriptfoo Glad it helped, although definitely not consciously ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reducing assumptions and inequation yields `False`

```
aF = (vF0 > 0 && vR0 > 0 && bFx > 0 && rho > 0 && aRx > 0 && bRx > 0 &&
      bFx > bRx) && Less[0, Times[Power[bFx, -1], vF0]] && 
   Less[Times[Power[bFx, -1], vF0], rho] && 
   Less[rho, 
    Times[Power[bRx, -1], 
     Plus[Times[aRx, rho], Times[bRx, rho], vR0]]] // Reduce

ineq = Times[Divide[1, 2], Power[bFx, -1], Power[bRx, -1], 
    Plus[Times[Power[aRx, 2], bFx, Power[rho, 2]], 
     Times[aRx, bFx, bRx, Power[rho, 2]], 
     Times[-1, bRx, Power[vF0, 2]], Times[2, aRx, bFx, rho, vR0], 
     Times[2, bFx, bRx, rho, vR0], Times[bFx, Power[vR0, 2]]]] <= 
   Times[Divide[1, 2], Power[bFx, -2], 
    Plus[Times[aRx, Power[vF0, 2]], Times[-1, bFx, Power[vF0, 2]], 
     Times[2, bFx, vF0, vR0]]] // Simplify

red = Reduce[ineq && aF]

(*   False   *)
```